# How to print .html files using ShellExecuteExW?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing

The goal is to print a htm/html file via Windows-API `::ShellExecuteExW`.

The parameters of `::ShellExecuteExW` are

```
shell_info.lpVerb = "open";
shell_info.lpFile = "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe";
shell_info.lpParameters = "C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll ,PrintHTML "C:\Temp\test.html"";
```

`lpFile` and `lpParameters` are fetched from the registry key `"\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\print\command"`

The error message:
[image]

Everything is fine if running the `C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\mshtml.dll ,PrintHTML "C:\Temp\test.html"` via cmd. The printing dialog appears.

How does `::ShellExecuteExW` need to be called to achieve the same behavior as the cmd?

Comment: Instead of fiddling with internal implementation details, why not simply pass the `"print"` verb? It's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow) purpose is: *"Prints the document file specified by `lpFile`."*

Comment: @IInspectable in this case I get an error message _"This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page."_ It might be easy to fix on the local machine, but I guess our users will get the same message.

Comment: They sure would. The alternative is to keep using MSHTML, and *ancient* HTML implementation, capable of rendering next to no HTML documents these days.

Comment: Also: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Comment: @ViktorBe then you must have done something else wrong, because based on the configuration you have shown, invoking the `print` verb on the `.html` file itself should invoke the same `rundll32` command you are trying to invoke manually. Did you verify in the Registry that the `.html` file extension actually maps to the `htmlfile` progid and not to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that the code that generates the error in the screenshot looks different from what you show us here? I'm asking this because you don't seem to escape any double quote or backslash. Seems to me your compiler should at least give one error when compiling that code.

However I just tried the code below and this seem to work. Hope it helps.

```
int main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shell_info = { 0 };
    shell_info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW);
    shell_info.lpVerb = L"open";
    shell_info.lpFile = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe";
    shell_info.lpParameters = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\mshtml.dll ,PrintHTML \"C:\\Temp\\test.html\"";
    shell_info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ShellExecuteExW(&shell_info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just found the mistake in our wrapper of `::ShellExecuteExW`. The `lpFile` parameter was capitalized which caused `PrintHTML` to become `PRINTHMTL` and this was the root cause.